# Php web socket (server side)

Tags: php, javascript, websocket, phpwebsocket

Hello i have been getting into ajax and JavaScript web dev lately and was looking for a way to have the browser update when new info is received i finally found it ... WebSockets I can do the client side and JavaScript fine but the server side is escaping me i just dont get it. I would like it to be done in php because it a language i understand... I've done a lot of searching but the pages google give me don't explain.

Anyways long story short i would like to be pointed to a simple php websocket script. Ill dissect it myself and come back if i need any help.

Sorry This prob seems like bad research but i have been looking for a easy script for days that i can understand.

Thank you in advanced!

**Edit:**

After much work with Sockets I highly recommend NodeJS. It's good at what it does. Php also has some problems with mutlithreading (which is pretty much a necessity for WebSockets).

At the time of asking this question I didn't make it clear that I didn't want to use a library. I just wanted a small script.

Comment: Also i am very new to sockets so if you guys have something better please suggest

Comment: Have a look at [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: php isn't a great language for web sockets. may want to look into node.js. it's server-side javascript, and perfect for things like this.

Comment: @TomKnapen what does curl have to do with socket servers exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share **Ratchet websockets**.

it has fair documentations and explaination on how it works, you just need a little time to understand and research about it.

you can start by looking it's Process Flow http://socketo.me/docs/flow

Good Luck! :)

PS. You need ngnix for your server to have SSL support or use stunnel3 if you really insist on using apache. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ratchet-php/0P920TwwAuk